# How to animate the nested view on constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I have a requirement where the view needs to be at the center of bottom and adjust the height based on its content. So created `constraint layout` inside root `constraint layout` to acheive this. But now I am facing a problem with animation. I am not able to apply `constraintSet`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BEE">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/error_try_again"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:minWidth="180dp"
            android:text="Try again"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/error_subtitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="We are unable to find the object"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:text="Try to keep the camera steady"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/error_title" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- If I need to go with `constraintSet` how to restructure my layout (without nested groups)?
- Is there any other way we can achieve it? I feel like `constraintSet` is much straight forward to use.

Tried calling this animation constraint set which will pass nested constraint as param `error_layout`. But no changes on the result:

```
    private void animateResult(ConstraintLayout constraint) {
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.frameout_layout);

        Transition transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(1.0f));
        transition.setDuration(1200);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraint, transition);

        constraintSet.applyTo(constraint);
    }
```

Layout:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem with ContraintSet and it's animation? Because it's working just fine.

Comment: @GensaGames I have updated the animation snippet above. No changes on calling animation func.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you should provide a reproducible example of what you have, and something like image/video of what you want to achieve. I've copied your XML and is bad displayed on my device, looks like there's something else missing.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I have updated the actual look. can you please try with this?

Comment: What do you want to do? What's the animation needed? The code above in `animateResult()` isn't doing anything because you've not changed anything. What do you expect it to do when you're not doing any change in that?

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` is very advanced, even if you go further for animations, then comes `MotionLayout` in `ConstraintLayout` with Adobe After Effects lookalike animator by which you can create any kind of animations with ease. But, I don't get it what animation do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to transition the `error_layout` constraint from down (out of frame) to up (in frame) which is already defined starting position in another layout. So finally trying to achieve the transition using constraintSet with these two layout. @LalitFauzdar

Comment: Ah, it's easy. Wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remember, ConstraintSet Animation works as any other animation with two stages - Animation Start and Animation End. So, First set the view constraint as Animation start which means hidden under bottom of the layout.

So, Change the initial constraints as:

```
<!-- Here app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf will position the view under the layout/screen -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/error_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
```

Then, create the constraints as

```
//rootLayout is the Id of the parent layout
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(rootLayout)
constraintSet.clear(error_layout.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
constraintSet.connect(error_layout.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
val transition: Transition = ChangeBounds()
transition.interpolator = AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(1.0f)
transition.duration = 1200
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout, transition)
constraintSet.applyTo(rootLayout)
```

Then, if you want to hide it again. Just replace the TOP and BOTTOM as

```
constraintSet.clear(error_layout.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
constraintSet.connect(error_layout.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
```

[image]

GIF took more time than coding :p.

**EDIT** - To listen to animation updates, especially Animation end as requested, what you can do is you can set a listener on `transition` as

```
transition.addListener(object : Transition.TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionStart(transition: Transition) {
    }
    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
    }
    override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition) {
    }
    override fun onTransitionPause(transition: Transition) {
    }
    override fun onTransitionResume(transition: Transition) {
    }
})
```

Put it just before the `beginDelayedTransition()`.

Comment: Thanks mate! It is working fine and thanks for your time!. Actually, I'm new to android and wasn't aware of the programmatic change.

Comment: How do we know when the transition ends? I want to set the visibility to `GONE`.

Comment: @Balasubramanian I've added the listener, you can check it. You can use `onTransitionEnd()` to get a callback when transition ends.

Answer (score 1):

I think simplest way would be to use transition manager.

Something like this

```
 findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
        val constraint = if (changed) constraintSet1 else constraintSet2
        constraint.applyTo(constraintLayout)
```

P.S. - Oh i see someonce has already said the same and with better explaination.

Comment: what is `constraintSet1` and `constraintSet2`? Can you define to understand better?

Comment: @Balasubramanian As you can see in my answer, I've declared a `constraintSet` as `val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()` and then I've changed the constraints of the layout to animate. Just like that, these two `constraintSet1` and `constraintSet` are two pre-declared `ConstraintSet`, one for the first stage and one for the second stage of the animation. Nothing new, nothing confusing. And because a `ConstraintSet` is applied only when you call `applyTo()`, you can create two different `ConstraintSet` prior to the animation and can use them just like this answer.