# Animate a constraintlayout transition using only one layout file

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I have been using constraintlayout animations using two layout files

```
private void animate() {
        ConstraintSet set1 = new ConstraintSet();
        set1.clone(root);

        ConstraintSet set2 = new ConstraintSet();
        set2.clone(this, R.layout.layout_file_2);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root, transition);
        set2.applyTo(root);
}
```

However, in the layout i am only changing two constraints. I decided to try doing so programmatically and did this, which worked.

```
private void showHidden() {
        ConstraintLayout parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.root_constraint_layout);
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(parentLayout);
        constraintSet.connect(R.id.search_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.toolbar_layout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        constraintSet.connect(R.id.search_layout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.root_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        constraintSet.applyTo(parentLayout);
}
```

This is however, not animated. I tried to animate as I did before in the first one (using only 1 layout file this time) and my result was this

```
private void animate2() {
        ConstraintLayout parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.root_constraint_layout);
        ConstraintSet set1 = new ConstraintSet();
        set1.clone(parentLayout);

        ConstraintSet set2 = new ConstraintSet();
        set2.clone(parentLayout);

        set2.connect(R.id.search_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.toolbar_layout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        set2.connect(R.id.search_layout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.root_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

        Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.END).setDuration(500);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parentLayout, transition);

        set2.applyTo(parentLayout);
 }
```

This works like the second one, but shows no animation, the new constraints immediately jump into place. Is there any way I can make the animation work without using two layoyuts? or is there something i'm doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate the nested view on constraint layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623673/how-to-animate-the-nested-view-on-constraint-layout)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clear the constraints on side of view on which you applying constraint set .
You can do this approach using

```
constraintSet.clear(view.Layout.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT) //You can change LEFT with whatever side you are choosing
```

Before connecting layout sides using connect function .

Here is the full code for getting it in better way :-

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet.clone(view.rootLayout)
    view.layout.animate().alpha(1f).duration = 700
    constraintSet.clear(view.layout.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
    constraintSet.connect(
        view.layout.id,
        ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
        ConstraintSet.RIGHT
    )
    view.layout.animate().translationX(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.zeroDP))
    val transition: Transition = ChangeBounds()
    transition.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.QUINT_OUT)
    transition.duration = 700
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(view.rootLayout, transition)
    constraintSet.applyTo(view.rootLayout)
```