# I am not able to give programatically constraint correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I have two buttons validate and notify as shown in the below image in XML.

[image]

I want to show validate button below notify button programmatically. as shown in the below image

[image]

I have implemented kotlin code and code sniped mentioned below:

```
fun changeConstraint() {
    val valetBtnParent = binding.root.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.childLayout)
    ConstraintSet().apply {
        val layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        clone(valetBtnParent)
        clear(R.id.button_validate, ConstraintSet.END)
        clear(R.id.button_validate, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        clear(R.id.button_validate, ConstraintSet.START)
        connect(R.id.button_validate, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.detail_cardview, ConstraintSet.TOP, ZERO)
        connect(R.id.button_validate, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.detail_cardview, ConstraintSet.END, ZERO)
        connect(R.id.button_validate, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.button_notify, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, TWO_HUNDRED)
        applyTo(childLayout)
    }
}
```

Please Help me!!!!

Comment: Post the XML if you can. What is `childLayout` defined as? You define but don't seem to use `layoutParams`. You are cloning `valetBtnParent` but applying the constraint set to `childLayout`. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way is inserting them into a Linearlayout and changing orientation from Horizontal to Vertical.

Answer (score 0):

A very important thing that you've missed is your XML layout which is very important when helping out in `ContraintLayout` animations as it tells what are the existing Constraints but let's just work on the provided code:

This is the expected Result as it seems:

[image]

To achieve it: You've to clear `Top`, `Bottom` and `End` constraints of the `button_validate` and `Start` (and `Bottom` if in use) of the `button_notify`.

To do that, you can change your code as:

```
fun changeConstraint() {
    ConstraintSet().apply {
        clone(binding.childLayout)
        clear(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        clear(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        clear(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.END)
        clear(binding.buttonNotify.id, ConstraintSet.START)
        connect(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, binding.detailCardview.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        connect(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END)
        connect(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, binding.buttonNotify.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, TWO_HUNDRED)
        connect(binding.buttonNotify.id, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START)
        applyTo(binding.childLayout)
    }
}
```

Assuming that the `detail_cardview` is below these buttons, the above code should work properly.

To add animation while changing the constraints, paste these lines above the last line which contains `applyTo()`:

```
val transition: Transition = ChangeBounds()
transition.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f)
transition.duration = 400
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.childLayout, transition)
```

To add an animation listener if needed, you can check out my other answer for `ConstraintSet` animation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65688828/8244632).

Because you were already using view binding, there was no logic to use static IDs and I've changed them to binding IDs as well. This should supposedly work, even though your code was incomplete. Do tell me if something is a miss.

Additionally, To achieve the output as seen in the GIF, The code that I've used for the GIF is as follows:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true -->
//To change the constraints to the new position
private fun changeConstraint() {
    ConstraintSet().apply {
        clone(binding.childLayout)
        clear(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.END)
        clear(binding.buttonNotify.id, ConstraintSet.START)
        clear(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        clear(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        connect(
            binding.buttonValidate.id,
            ConstraintSet.END,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.END
        )
        connect(
            binding.buttonValidate.id,
            ConstraintSet.TOP,
            binding.buttonNotify.id,
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
        )
        connect(
            binding.buttonNotify.id,
            ConstraintSet.START,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.START
        )
        val transition: Transition = ChangeBounds()
        transition.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f)
        transition.duration = 400
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.childLayout, transition)
        applyTo(binding.childLayout)
        isChanged = true
    }
}

//To change the constraints back to the original position
private fun changeConstraintBack() {
    ConstraintSet().apply {
        clone(binding.childLayout)
        clear(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.END)
        clear(binding.buttonNotify.id, ConstraintSet.START)
        clear(binding.buttonValidate.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        connect(
            binding.buttonValidate.id,
            ConstraintSet.END,
            binding.buttonNotify.id,
            ConstraintSet.START,
            5
        )
        connect(
            binding.buttonValidate.id,
            ConstraintSet.TOP,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.TOP
        )
        connect(
            binding.buttonValidate.id,
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
        )
        connect(
            binding.buttonNotify.id,
            ConstraintSet.START,
            binding.buttonValidate.id,
            ConstraintSet.END
        )
        val transition: Transition = ChangeBounds()
        transition.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f)
        transition.duration = 400
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.childLayout, transition)
        applyTo(binding.childLayout)
        isChanged = false
    }
}
```